# React-query: Make new query with useInfiniteQuery with different parameters

Tags: reactjs

I'm in the process of setting up useInfiniteQuery to fetch jobs from the Github Jobs API. I have yet to set up the actual infinite query with a load more button, but right now I want to understand how can I reset the information from data that useInfiniteQuery returns and make a new query with new parameters, which I'm currently using as a state that gets set with react-hook-forms.

```
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useState({
    text: '',
    location: '',
    fullTime: false
  });

  const fetchJobs = async (key, page = 1) => {
    const { text, location, fullTime } = searchParams;
    try {
      const res = await fetch(
        `https://api.allorigins.win/get?url=${encodeURIComponent(
          `https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?description=${text}&page=${page}&location=${location}&full_time=${fullTime}`
        )}`
      );
      const json = await res.json();
      const results = JSON.parse(await json.contents);
      return {
        results,
        nextPage: page + 1
      };
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const {status, data, error, isFetching, isFetchingMore, fetchMore, canFetchMore
  } = useInfiniteQuery('jobs', fetchJobs, {
    getFetchMore: (lastGroup, allGroups) => lastGroup.nextPage
  });

  const onSubmit = async data => {
    const { text, location, fullTime } = data;
    setSearchParams({
      text,
      location,
      fullTime
    });
    // Want to make a new query call to fetch new Jobs with different parameters

    // Using refetchOnWindowFocus uses the parameters from the new searchParams state,
    // but using useQueryCache.refetchQueries() here does not, neither does
    // expecting fetchJobs to get the updated state, as fetchJobs seems to always use the
    // initial searchParams state
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Search onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} ref={register} />
      {isFetching && <p>Loading...</p>}
      {data && <p>Got data</p>}
    </>
  );
```

As commented, when I try to just submit the form, the the state updates, but fetchJobs never gets the updated state.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass in any data that may update as part of the query params in array form as the key. Or a deep equal as the deps on form data.

```
const {status, data, error, isFetching, isFetchingMore, fetchMore, canFetchMore
  } = useInfiniteQuery(['jobs', text, location, fullTime], fetchJobs, {
    getFetchMore: (lastGroup, allGroups) => lastGroup.nextPage
  });
```

Link for more info
https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/query-functions

Comment: Hadn't found the query functions doc page, thanks! I got it working.